# Web parts disappear almost instantly

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part, list-view-web-part

I have a site that requires a list web part. When I add it to the page, it appears for a couple of seconds. The page then reloads as if it were refreshed, and then disappears,  exiting Edit mode at the same time.

I've tried looking elsewhere for answers but can't find any. I've found a few issues concerning disappearing web parts but it's not quite the same.

I've had this issue before, but on a different site, and in the end the issue just resolved itself somehow, which doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Add "**?Contents=1**" at end of page URL and check if web part appears in list or not. For more detail on this, please have a look at link below:
[List All web parts on page](http://blogs.sharepoint911.com/blogs/jennifer/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=92)

Comment: Thanks for the link. There were about ten of the same web part in the list where I'd kept adding them. I tried closing one of them then adding it from Closed Web Parts but still nothing.

Comment: Do you get any events of "High" or "Unexpected" severity in ULS logs when you add web part?